# let $A\in M_{10}(\mathbb{R})$ and every row of $A$ has exactly one non zero element . find eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

let $A\in M_{10}(\mathbb{R})$ and every row of $A$ has exactly one non zero element .
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 &0 &\ldots  & 0\\ 0 & 0 &1 &\ldots  & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & & \vdots  \\ 0 & 0 &0 &\ldots  & 1 \\ (10)^{10} & 0 &0 &\ldots  & 0\end{bmatrix}  _{10 \times 10}$$

now which of following options is eigenvalue of $A$ ?

$ \\1)0 \\ 2)1  \\ 3)10 \\4) (10)^{10}$

I find $det (A)= (10)^{10}$ .but we must find $det (A- \lambda I)$   and find characteristic polynomial of $A$ and roots of characteristic polynomial is eigenvalues of $A$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is the transpose of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) so its characteristic and minimal polynomial are equal to $x^{10} - 10^{10}$.

Therefore, the spectrum of $A$ is precisely the set of real roots of $x^{10} - 10^{10}$, which are $\pm 10$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is $A.v$ if $v=(1,10,10^2,\ldots,10^9)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^{10}=10^{10}I$, which rules out  most answers.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix
$$
A-xI=
\begin{bmatrix}-x & 1 &0 &\ldots  & 0 &0\\ 0 & -x &1 &\ldots  &0 &0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 & 0 &0 &\ldots  &-x &1 \\ 10^{10} & 0 &0 &\ldots  &0 & -x\end{bmatrix}  _{10 \times 10}
$$ 
has only two generalized diagonals not containing a zero:

- The main diagonal, with signed product $x^{10}$.$\\[4pt]$

  The off diagonal (consisting of all ones), together with the entry $10^{10}$, with signed product $-10^{10}$.

It follows that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^{10}-10^{10}$, which has only two real roots, namely $\pm 10$.